# C++ map in a class, how do I make a member accessor

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm new to maps. I need a class that constructs seating for a performance (there are many performances). Here's what I have so far:

```
// header stuff/libraries

Seats::Seats()
{
    map< const string, bool > seat;

    seat["A1"] = false;
    seat["A2"] = false;
    /* more seats .. */
}
```

Do I need to create an access member if I want to update a seat? If can so can I have an example please?

Comment: `seat` is not a data member so it won't be usable outside of the constructor.  Declaring the key type as `const` is redundant because the key type is automatically const-qualified.

Comment: As the code snippets show, don't have your class accessor functions leak out the encapsulation details i.e. you are using map or set or something else. Just work on std::string at the interface level

Answer (score 4):

as others have indicated, your map variable needs to be a data member of the class not in the local scope of the Seats constructor as you've posted

```
class Seats {
public:
   Seats();
   bool GetSeat(const string &);
   void SetSeat(const string &, bool);

private:
   map< string, bool > seat;

};

Seats::Seats() {
    // merely your example values posted.
    seat["A1"] = false;
    seat["A2"] = false;
}

void Seats::SetSeat(const string &seat_number, bool occupied) {
    seat[seat_number] = occupied;   
}

bool Seats::GetSeat(const string &seat_number) {
    return seat[seat_number];
}
```

keep in mind using the map's [] operator though can cause elements to be inserted into the data structure if they do not exist yet:
[link text](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/)

> T& operator[] ( const key_type& x );
>   If x does not match the key of any
>   element in the container, the function
>   inserts a new element with that key
>   and returns a reference to its mapped
>   value. Notice that this always
>   increases the map size by one, even if
>   no mapped value is assigned to the
>   element (the element is constructed
>   using its default constructor).

Comment: +1 i suspect the next question is - what if i also want to store the name of the person sitting in the seat?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started.

```
class Seats {
private: // private section: implementation details here
    set< string > reservations;

public: // public section: accessors here
    bool is_reserved( string const &id ) const {
        return reservations.count( id );
    }

    bool reserve( string const &id ) { // return false if res. already existed
        return reservations.insert( id ).second;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why to have `reservations.count( id )` ... a set will anyway hold unique values only. Shall we not try to `find` it?

Comment: @Hemant: Then you have to compare against `reservations.end()`. Same complexity, but this is shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a container (like `std::map`) as a data member in a class, you need to put it with the rest of the data members for the class, in the class definition.

A curios (intentional) property of std::map is that `operator[]` default constructs values for keys that aren't already in the collection, so unless you actually need to get a list of the (`false` by default) keys, there's no need to initialize them.